# "Снеговик" и "снежная баба" - является ли выбор слова региональным предпочтением?

Tags: выбор-слов

В одной из программ центрального ТВ я обратил внимание на многократное употребление в разговоре ведущих слова "снеговик". Мне оно всегда казалось *книжным* - в моем детстве сооружение из трех больших комов снега в быту называлось "снежной бабой". У меня две версии: a) слово "снеговик" предпочитают в Москве, подобно "бордюру" и выражениям вроде "один в один" (вместо "один к одному" и "один на один") и б) это слово со временем стало вытеснять "снежную бабу" повсеместно (под влиянием английского snowman?). А какой вариант предпочитают участники форума?

Comment: Спасибо за вопрос накануне Нового Года, полезно иногда вспоминать свою историю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно и так сказать - региональный выбор, европейцы говорят только "снеговик", в России раньше говорили чаще всё-таки "снежная баба", теперь сближаемся с европейцами. Но ведь когда мы произносим эти слова, мы представлявляем себе не одно и то же - снеговик всё же мужчина, а снежная баба - женщина, одевают их по-разному, на бабе часто фартук. Всё-таки где-то там в мозгу у нас история этих фигур осталась.

> Жители северных стран лепили снеговиков еще в глубокой древности.
> Снежные фигуры, напоминающие людей, изначально были такими же идолами,
> как и изображения из дерева, камня, соломы. “ В древние времена всем
> народам был присущ единый и общий ритуально-обрядовый первосюжет... .
> Ежегодное прощание со старым годом или прощание с зимой, которая шла
> на отдых; прощание со смертью в весенних празднествах воплощало
> главные фазы существования божества — его смерть и возрождение...
> <...>
> Участники обряда «создавали» божество разными способами: в виде
> деревянного идола, чучела из тряпья, снежной бабы, куклы из соломы,
> снопа, одетой в лохмотья лопаты. Алексей Кононенко, «Энциклопедия
> славянской культуры, письменности и мифологии»
>
> По сути своей русская
> снежная баба родственна чучелу Масленицы, которое сжигают, провожая
> зиму. И Масленицу, и снежную бабу некоторые исследователи возводят к
> образу богини Марены, или Макоши — главного женского божества славян.
> Изначально Марена символизировала смерть и возрождение, смену времен
> года, плодородие, но позднее ее стали считать лишь воплощением зимы и
> смерти.
>
> Славяне приписывали снегу магическую силу. Его ассоциировали с
> богатством, изобилием и плодовитостью. По народным приметам снежная
> морозная зима обещала хороший урожай и жаркое лето. Считалось, что
> снег, собранный в определенные дни, имеет целебную силу. Своеобразный
> отголосок языческих представлений о снежной бабе сохранила русская
> сказка «Снегурочка»: “ Вот они вылепили носик, сделали две ямочки во
> лбу, и только что Иван прочертил ротик, как из него вдруг дохнуло
> теплым духом. Иван второпях отнял руку, только смотрит — ямочки во лбу
> стали уж навыкате, и вот из них поглядывают голубенькие глазки, вот уж
> и губки как малиновые улыбаются.
>
> — Что это? Не наваждение ли какое? — сказал Иван, кладя на себя
> крестное знамение.
>
> А кукла наклоняет к нему головку, точно живая, и зашевелила ручками и
> ножками в снегу, словно грудное дитя в пеленках.
>
> — Ах, Иван, Иван! — вскричала Марья, задрожав от радости. — Это нам
> Господь дитя дает! — и бросилась обнимать Снегурочку, а со Снегурочки
> весь снег отвалился, как скорлупа с яичка, и на руках у Марьи была уже
> в самом деле живая девочка. «Снегурочка» в обработке Александра
> Афанасьева Однако, в отличие от чучела Масленицы, снежная баба
> утратила свое магическое значение так давно, что сохранилась в
> народной памяти лишь как символ зимней забавы.
>
> В Северной Европе была распространена **мужская ипостась** «снежного
> идола» — снеговик. Самое раннее известное науке изображение снеговика
> датируется 1380 годом. Оно украшает поля Часослова, хранящегося в
> Голландии. По мнению исследователя Боба Экштейна, это доказывает, что
> к тому времени снеговик был широко известным персонажем, входил в
> «культурный код» средневекового человека.
>
> Вероятно, уже в XIV веке европейцы лепили снеговиков исключительно для
> развлечения. Связанные с ними суеверия долгое время сохранялись лишь в
> Норвегии. Там делали из снега «белых троллей», которые защищали от
> злых духов.
>
> В художественной литературе одним из первых снеговика упомянул Уильям
> Шекспир. В его хронике «Ричард II» 1597 года фигурирует некий «снежный
> король» — «king of snow»: “ О горе! Столько зим прожив на свете, Не
> знаю, как мне называть себя! О, если б я был шуточный король, Из снега
> слепленный, и мог растаять, Растечься мог под солнцем Болингброка!
> «Ричард II», перевод Михаила Донского
>
> Современное название снеговика возникло в XVIII веке в немецком языке.
> В 1770 году в Лейпциге вышел сборник детских песен, который включал
> песенку «Schneemann». После этого в английском языке закрепилось слово
> «snowman». **Русское слово «снеговик» получило распространение лишь в XX
> веке.** Например, в произведениях Александра Пушкина и Антона Чехова оно
> не встречается ни разу.

https://www.culture.ru/s/vopros/snegoviki/

Так что на Руси снежная баба -отголосок языческих верований, будто воздух населен небесными девицами, повелевавшими туманами, облаками, снегами, в их честь язычники устраивали торжественные ритуалы. Чтобы умилостивить небесных обитательниц, они и лепили снежных баб, как бы возвеличивая небесных нимф на земле. В деталях их «одеяния» угадывается мистический характер. Например, нос в виде морковки прикрепляли, чтобы умилостивить языческих духов, посылающих урожай и плодородие. Перевернутое ведро на голове символизировало достаток в доме. Один из ритуалов проводился для защиты от сильных морозов в день зимнего солнцестояния (25 декабря). Надо было помочь солнцу набрать силу — поэтому крестьяне жгли костры, катали горящие колеса, символизирующие светило. Чтобы зима была не слишком суровой, лепили снежную бабу, изображавшую зиму, водили вокруг нее хороводы.

Так что я предпочитаю и слово "снежная баба", и вид именно бабы, а не мужской особи снежного человека - недоброго  снежного монстра впечатляющих размеров.

Под влиянием христианства снеговики считались языческими рукотворными идолами,  которые представляют реальную угрозу для людей. Думали, что особенно опасно лепить их в периоды полнолуния: для человека это может обернуться навязчивыми кошмарными сновидениями, ночными страхами, да и вообще всяческими неудачами. А в Норвегии существовало предание о том, что снеговиков опасно разглядывать поздним вечером из-за шторы. К тому же, дурным знаком считалось встретить снежную фигуру ночью: ее рекомендовалось обойти стороной. В Румынии издавна известен обычай украшать снеговика «бусами» из головок чеснока. Считалось, что это способствует здоровью домочадцев и оберегает их от проказ темной силы. Только в XIX веке, когда христианские догмы начали утрачивать свое былое влияние, европейские снежные создания «подобрели» и вскоре стали незаменимым атрибутом Рождества и Нового года.

А след-то этих знаний всё равно остался, и "снеговик", который сейчас используется как более культурный синоним "снежной бабы", мне всё-таки чужд. Мы с детьми лепили снежную бабу!

Answer (score 2):

В моём детстве — *снежная баба*. Сейчас говорю и *снеговик*, и *снежная баба*...

Как показывают материалы Нацкорпуса, *снеговик* стал теснить *снежную бабу* лишь в последние лет тридцать.

См. **[снежная баба](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/graphic.xml?smoothing=3&g=i_year_created&graphic_from_result=1&lang=ru&sort=i_year_created&lex1=%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&parent1=0&startyear=1800&lex2=%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0&max2=1&text=lexgramm&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&level1=0&level2=0&api=1.0&mode=graphic_main&env=alpha&min2=1&endyear=2019&nodia=1&parent2=0)**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

См. **[снеговик](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/graphic.xml?smoothing=3&g=i_year_created&graphic_from_result=1&lang=ru&sort=i_year_created&lex1=%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA&parent1=0&startyear=1800&max2=1&text=lexgramm&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&level1=0&level2=0&api=1.0&mode=graphic_main&env=alpha&min2=1&endyear=2019&nodia=1&parent2=0)**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

На такой вопрос трудно дать хоть сколько-нибудь объективный ответ.
Но если сугубо субъективные мнения в данном случае принимаются (вопреки общей политике ресурса), то попробую.

Мне в детстве (летом - подмосковном, зимой - харьковском; сказать, где именно я подцепил слово, не берусь) тоже ближе была "снежная баба". Но со временем я стал воспринимать эту бабу именно как детское, разговорное. Оно и понятно, ребенку на слух "баба" куда ближе какого-то там "-овика". Тем более, что "баба" воспринимается как "бабушка", "бабка", в крайнем случае - женщина. Хотя на самом деле подозреваю, что тут совсем другое значение - то же, что и в "ромовой бабе" - нечто слепленное, сформированное из сыпучего или вязкого материала или вытесанное из камня (истукан).
В БТС Кузнецова есть эти значения, правда бабу ромовую от бабы-истукана от отделяет, а "баба", которой дома ломают (деталь ударного или таранного устройства), вообще отдельным значением идет, но это уже другой вопрос.

Видимо, я был не совсем прав, эта "баба" только воспринимается как детское, но на самом деле вполне адекватное название снежного истукана. Такое понимание исключает отсылки к якобы региональному характеру слова. Сам же проверить не могу, ибо совершенно не располагаю хоть какой-то представительной выборкой.

А вот то, что "снеговик" вытесняет "бабу", с этим согласен. Я первый раз обратил на это внимание еще совсем юным, в 60-х годах появился "Снеговик" как символ международного предновогоднего хоккейного турнира на приз "Известий". Понятно, что назвать этого маскота "Бабой" было бы неприлично. Но и "Снеговик" тогда звучало несколько непривычно. Выбрали, естественно, из двух зол меньшее. Вот так мне запомнилось появление "Снеговика".